# How to make a queue in Java using rows from a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, data-structures, queue, nodes

I am a beginner in Java and SQL databases and would like some help.

I am trying to make a program which accesses stored data from a phpMyAdmin (MySQL) database table. I know how to `SELECT` already. The data is of a list of medicines with all the information about them. The column headings are as follows: name, day_of_week_to_take, expiry, manufacturer, etc.

But I want to create Queue Abstract Data Structure with the rows of the table.

I want to create `Nodes` for each row. I will first have to create a `class Node` So for the first row, it will create a `Node` with the data from each column of that row. I will then have to create `push` and `pull` methods. (However, I believe there is already a Java library that can do this?) How can I create this Queue?

The queue will be used to store the order of timings. Each `Node` object will have it's own day of the week when it occurs.

E.g. Take medicine A on Monday, medicine B on Tuesday. The queue should order each of the medicines in order of the days of the week.

Please ask for any information that I have not provided. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I SHOULD HAVE MADE THIS CLEAR:
The days are stored as a `String`:
e.g if I need to take the medicine on Monday the string is:
`1000000`. Each position in this 7 character string corresponds to the days of the week. So if I have to take the medicine on Saturday and Sunday: `0000011`. And so on...

Comment: why not use available Queue in java's Collection framework?

Comment: @eatSleepCode what is that, what are you talking about? I don't know what "Java Collection Framework" is. Please can you explain?

Comment: I hope u can select the rows from db order by day_of_week_to_take.. If not how u r getting the rows?

Comment: @kaushik I am sorry, but I don't know how to select rows in order. SO are you saying that instead of getting all the data and then putting it in order, I should just get it from the database in the order I want it? I have edited my question

Comment: Yes there is a functionality order by <column name> to get the data ordered by the specific column. Just an example if u have a table name student. It has three column student_id, student_name, student_city. Now if u wrote a query select * from student order by student_city. It will give you the row sorted by the student_city. Example. If a student is from city ABC bt his id is 10 and another student is from EFG and his id is 1. On the result set the student record having the city id ABC will come first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the possible solution. I tried to make it as generic as possible.
I made some assumption ..
i. I did not set the database.I populate the Node class object through constructor. In your case you make the Node class object by the database row. Each row in the  data base correspondence to one object of the Node class.

```
public class Node {

    private String mediName;
    private String dayOfWeek;
    private String expiry;
    private String manufacturer;


    public Node(String mediName,String dayOfWeek,String expiry,String manufacturer)
    {
        this.mediName=mediName;
        this.dayOfWeek=dayOfWeek;
        this.expiry=expiry;
        this.manufacturer=manufacturer;
    }


    public String getMediName() {
        return mediName;
    }
    public void setMediName(String mediName) {
        this.mediName = mediName;
    }
    public String getDayOfWeek() {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }
    public void setDayOfWeek(String dayOfWeek) {
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }
    public String getExpiry() {
        return expiry;
    }
    public void setExpiry(String expiry) {
        this.expiry = expiry;
    }
    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }
    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }


}
```

the below class is designed to operate as a Queue datastructure.

```
public class QueueNode {

    private int front=-1;
    private int rear=-1;
    private int capacity;
    private Node[] arr;

    public QueueNode(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity=capacity;
        arr=new Node[capacity];
    }

    private boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return front==-1;
    }

    private boolean isFull()
    {
        return (rear+1)%capacity==front;
    }

    public void push(Node data) throws Exception
    {
        if(isFull())
            throw new Exception("Queue is Full");
        else
        {
            rear=(rear+1)%capacity;
            arr[rear]=data;
            if(front==-1)
                front=rear;
        }

    }

    public Node pull() throws Exception
    {
        Node data=null;
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw new Exception("Queue is Empty");
        }else
        {
            data=arr[front];
            if(front==rear)
                front=rear-1;
            else
            {
                front=(front+1)%capacity;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

the function of the below class is to test Node and QueueNode class..

```
public class MainClassForQueue {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Node n1=new Node("A","1000000","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n2=new Node("B","1100000","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n3=new Node("C","0100000","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n4=new Node("D","0010000","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n5=new Node("F","1010000","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n6=new Node("G","0000001","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n7=new Node("H","0000011","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n8=new Node("I","0001000","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n9=new Node("J","0000100","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n10=new Node("K","0000010","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n11=new Node("L","1010101","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n12=new Node("M","1001011","2017-02-16","ABC");
            Node n13=new Node("N","1111111","2017-02-16","ABC");

            List<Node> listNode=new ArrayList<Node>();
            listNode.add(n1);
            listNode.add(n2);
            listNode.add(n3);
            listNode.add(n4);
            listNode.add(n5);
            listNode.add(n6);
            listNode.add(n7);
            listNode.add(n8);
            listNode.add(n9);
            listNode.add(n10);
            listNode.add(n11);
            listNode.add(n12);
            listNode.add(n13);

            int size=listNode.size();
            QueueNode queue=new QueueNode(7*size);

            for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listNode.size(); i++) {

                    Node data=listNode.get(i);
                    String day=data.getDayOfWeek();
                    if(day.charAt(j)=='1')
                        queue.push(data);
                }

            }

            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());
            System.out.println(queue.pull().getMediName());


        }

    }
```